# VBA input Box- cancel and Variable Setting

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code. I am writing a Macro to go on a button on the first page of an excel report that will take users to different tabs in the report based on the number they use. The issue is if I use the integer variable, if a user cancels the box or hits the x a error occurs. The numbers work fine in regards to the sheets with this. However, if i dim it as Variant an error no longer occurs, but then the numbers input no longer work. For ex. 3 brings up the invalid sheet box even if there are 8 sheets in the workbook. I think the variant is causing the input numbers to be a different format from integer? I think I can use the on error resume, but I was just wondering what that would look like. Or if there is another way to do this without using that method

```
Public Sub Summary_select()

     Dim x As Integer


     x = InputBox("Please Input The Sheet Number")


     If Not (IsNumeric(x)) Then
     MsgBox ("User Cancelled")
     ElseIf x = 0 Then
     MsgBox ("User Entered an Invalid Number of sheets")
     ElseIf x > Sheets.Count Then
     MsgBox ("User Entered an Invalid Number of sheets")
     Else
     Sheets(x).Activate
     Range("A1").Select
     End If

     End Sub
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992958/inputbox-cancel-different-from-vbnullstring-null/44993848#44993848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputBox` returns a `String`, so `Dim x as String`

Then once you have validated that it is numeric and within the correct range, use it as a number like this:

```
Worksheets(Val(x)).Activate
```

And do the same for your checks:

```
ElseIf Val(x) = 0 Then
```

Also, to critique your code a bit, what happens if the user enters -1? Technically, that's numeric, but not valid.

instead of `ElseIf Val(x) = 0 Then` you should use

```
ElseIf Val(x) < 1 Then
```

What about if they enter 1.5? You may want to also include a check for it being an integer:

```
If IsNumeric(x) Then
  If Val(x) <> Int(x) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Integer"
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. I am fairly new at VBA,  If you use an input box in this instance where you want a number returned to use later on in the code, do you always need to do something like this?

Comment: If you are askinig if an `InputBox` always returns a `String` the answer is yes. It's up to  you to validate it if you are expecting a numeric value.

Comment: Right so if I am expecting a number to use later one, i need to convert it when using it

Comment: Right, either that or have another variable that is an `Integer` and after you validate that it's numeric, set the `Integer` to `Val(x)` and you dont have to user `Val` over and over then.

Comment: Awesome Idea!  Thanks

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted. Also, the "User Cancelled" box is misleading. `If StrPtr(x) = 0 Then` would be the correct condition for displaying such a msgbox.

Comment: The more I look at all the validations and possible edge cases, the more this looks like a job for a dedicated, properly unit-tested function...

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wouldnt use an InputBox at all for this. I would make a Userform with a combobox and populate it with all the valid sheet numbers, or better yet, sheet names.

Comment: Ha, yea that a little bit above my vba skill right now

Comment: @Mat'sMug what is strptr?

Comment: @RPr it's an undocumented/hidden function that returns a memory offset for a string pointer =)  its little brothers are `VarPtr` and `ObjPtr`, respectively for getting the memory offset to a variable and an object pointer. You will find them in the Object Browser (F2) under the VBA standard library, in a module named `_HiddenModule`, only visible if you toggle the "Show hidden members" option from the object browser's context menu. `StrPtr(vbNullString)` returns `0`; `StrPtr("")` returns an address.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because when a use clicks cancel on an inputbox, the input box outputs an empty ***string*** - but the problem is your `Integer` declaration cannot accept a string.

So you could do something along the lines of:

```
On Error Resume Next
x = InputBox("Please Input The Sheet Number")
On Error Goto 0
```

And if an error occurs when passing the inputbox to `x`, then `x = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have much knowledge on vba core functionality, I've tried to modify your existing code to work the way you wanted. Give this a go:

```
Public Sub Summary_select()
     Dim x As String

     x = InputBox("Please Input The Sheet Number")

     If Not IsNumeric(x) Then
        MsgBox ("User Cancelled")
     ElseIf x = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("User Entered an Invalid Number of sheets")
     ElseIf x > Sheets.Count Then
        MsgBox ("User Entered an Invalid Number of sheets")
     Else
        Sheets("Sheet" & x).Activate
        Range("A1").Select
     End If
End Sub
```